# Reading and Parsing a PDF File using XML parser from server in Android

Tags: android

How to read and parse a PDF file URL inside parser from server in Android?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to say.
Maybe the case is that you have a PDF file and there are some inner URLs in the PDF that you are trying to access them through XML parsing?

If that's the case I don't think you can do that because first of all the PDF file is something like a "compress-signed" form that you can't have access to the contents(unlike .txt files). And I am pretty sure that you can't use XML parsing for parsing a PDF file.

An alternative solution is to search and download some third party application for processing PDF files.